# How to commit after Database.setSavePoint()

Tags: apex, batch, transaction

I have a batch Apex job that is currently wrapped in a single transaction, so that any exceptions will roll back the entire batch job.

I'm fighting locking issues in SF, and as part of this, I'd like to commit each record/iteration that I'm processing in my batch.  I still require a transaction for each record processed, but I don't need one transaction to have ALL iterations of updates contained in it.

I'm looking for how to commit one of these Database.setSavePoint() operations, but can't find any references to how to do this.

Comment: Each `execute` call is a complete transaction. A future execute can't cancel or rollback a prior execute. What makes you believe they are all wrapped into a single transaction?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough... The codebase I inherited has a Database.setSavePoint() call at the top of the execute() method.    It looks like the only way to commit work is to finish an execute() batch segment, eh?   Maybe just reduce size of batch..

Comment: yes - batch size of 1 could be the trick assuming you can't resolve the locking issues with other techniques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't explicitly commit a transaction. It is committed once the transaction ends successfully without an error. Note that each `execute` call in your batch is exactly one transaction. The results of a batch processing running from start to finish is 2 plus Records Processed divided by Batch Size, rounded up.

Example: Process 500 records in a batch size of 200 results in 2 transactions plus 3 `execute` transactions, for a total of 5. There is a higher level abstract process known as the chunk handler for large batches, but this higher level process commits each `execute` call fully upon completion. Try reducing your execution size in Database.executeBatch (scheduleBatch, etc) and see if that helps.

`Database.setSavePoint` has no effect (aside from the marker), by itself, but it allows you to later call Database.rollback if you want to undo everything that's happened since then.